# Local Maven Repository issue with multiple jars

Tags: java, spring, maven, mockito, maven-plugin

I have local Maven repository in `C:\Users\<User_Name>\.m2` directory. After getting "*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError...*" exception and navigating problem on the web, I see [this](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/10/javalangnosuchmethoderror.html) page mentioning to remove unused jar version(s) from local repository.

My questions are:

**1.** When I look at `C:\Users\<User_Name>\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core` folder, there are 52 different version folder. I think it is similar for other jar libraries. So, should we clean unused jars periodically? Or should we keep unused versions of a jar library?

**2.** If I just have `3.0.0` version of `mockito-core` in my `pom.xml`, how the app use or mix another version(s) in the local repository? Normally, if I just a single `mockito-core` dependency in my `pom.xml`, may there be any problem as mentioned on [that](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/10/javalangnosuchmethoderror.html) page (solving the problem after removing other jar version)?

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

You do not need to "clean unused jars" from your local maven repo manually. How do you want to decide which jar, which version is unused? Maybe your next project will use the jar that you want to delete. Who knows.

If you have enough disk space then you can leave your local maven repo directory untouched for years. If this directory grows too big, then I suggest you delete the complete `.m2` folder. Then the next time when you build a project, Maven will download automatically all dependencies that your project needs.

There is only one use-case when deleting your local maven repo can cause a headache: if you have installed some custom jars manually.

**2)**

It is highly possible that the different dependency versions that you see in your local Maven repo directory come from different projects that you built earlier.

Anyway, you can display your effective pon with the [Apache Maven Help Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good explanations. Actually, my approach similar you mentioned when disk space is not enough. As far as I know, when deleting m2 folder and rebuild maven dependencies, all of the necessary libraries are downloaded again. The only problem may be the jars that are installed manually, instead of pom.xml. Is that all true?

Comment: When there are multiple version of jar (for example `mockito-core` jar), if there is only one dependency of this `mockito-core` in pom.xml, how could the app use another version of `mockito-core`?

Comment: Yes. So before deleting your local maven repo, back up the JARs that you installed manually with [mvn install](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: Please ask one thing per topic. If my answer helped you then accept it as a solution and open a new topic with your new question.

Comment: Both are related questions and your answers still have not helped me completely. Before marked as answer, why do you clarify me about the second points ("... When there are multiple version of jar ...")?

Comment: Your questions are related to Maven. But they cover two different topics.

Comment: What about answering the second points ("... When there are multiple version of jar ...")?

Comment: **1.** Thanks for update. But what do you meant with "*Anyway, you can display your effective pon with the Apache Maven Help Plugin.*" ?

Comment: **2.** I think I could not explain the problem. I did not asked where the other versions of jars came from. I am just wondering, if there is only version x of `mockito-core` in the `pom.xml`, is it possible to be conflict with other versions in the local maven repo? Maybe due to manually adding `mockito-core`, etc.